# Aligning context inside a container

Tags: html, css, wordpress

hey guys so I am trying to build a page that has a main container where all the content goes in, in that container there is image that cover a certain amount of the container, a title to the left and a text to the right.

What I'm having problem with is how to put the text in a certain layout, I have a example that I can show that I'm trying to do:

[image]

and this image is what I already did:

[image]

this is what I have in the wordpress back office of the webpage.

```
 <div id="content">
     [getImgTag name="servicos-Financeiro" class="imgresize"]
     <b>Aconselhamento Financeiro</b>
     <hr size="3" color="blue" width="190px" align="left">  
 </div>
```

This is the respective attributes that I gave the id "content".

```
 #content {
    /*width: 750px;*/
    height:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

With that I'm trying to replicate exactly is the same layout with a title to the left and a text to the right, if you need to see anymore code from me you are free to ask!

Comment: The information you have provided isn't really enough to help you out. We can't help you out without more details since your question is too vague.

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis Gatzoulis I'm trying to replicate the results of the image

Comment: I understand but the StackOverflow guidelines require you post specific questions regarding specific issues. We cannot help you out by building the entire template page for you, unfortunately.

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis yeah I understand I hope this edit helped a little

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what it looks like you're asking is for a hand with the css, to align the sort of Header Text that you have to the left underneath the main image (not the background image). Your attempt is the second image, but you wish the formatting to match that of the first image - in essence creating two columns, one that contains the header, and one that contains the article text, with indents along the top and to the sides of the header column. (Drawing circles around the area in the images to look at may be useful for those not knowing where to look)

Comment: @KyleFairns the answer that was given to my question solved this issue, next time I will try to be more specific with my question thanks for the heads up, and sorry for not being explicit enough still new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this little example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxsgrpy1/)

Basically you create two columns and then you can apply style to each one.

```
.popup-title{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.popup-text{
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: when I put the text in a <p> tag it dissapears.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kxsgrpy1/1/) I did it, and the text is still visible...

Comment: I was able to do it with the help of your code thank you alot!